# How to export heterogeneous data to single file?

Tags: graphics, json-format

I want to export structured heterogeneous data (containing images) to some standard file format. The expression to export can contain 3 atomic types: numbers, strings, images, and be nested with 2 structures: lists and rules.

I thought maybe JSON could do the trick but doing this directly won't work:

[image]

And my workaround fails to maintain the standardness of the data (only Mathematica can read it)

```
img = Import["http://i.imgur.com/59L1rBp.png", "Image"]

js = ExportString[img, "JPEG"] // Compress;

Export["~/test.json", <|"a" -> {<|"a" -> {234523452, 3452345}|>}, 
  "ImageInsideTheJson" -> js|>, "JSON"]

ImportString[
 Uncompress@
  Import["~/test.json", "RawJSON"]["ImageInsideTheJson"], "JPEG"]
```

[image]

My question is, are there other file types or ways to achieve this seemingly simple request of ***system independent serialization of lists that contain strings AND images.***

Comment: Well, JSON cannot hold images.  It only supports certain data types, including strings and arrays of numbers.  It is up to you to decide on *how* to encode an image into such a format.  This is not a limitation of Mathematica.  It is a limitation of the JSON format.

Comment: Yes I know that, all in asking is if export string + compress is the way to go

Comment: That all depends on what you want to achieve.  It is one possible way.  Disadvantages I see: 1. quality loss from JPEG compression (you could `Compress` the `Image` directly, but the result will be much larger) 2. can only be read using Mathematica

Comment: @Szabolcs I don't believe #2 is true, if i copy paste the generated string into a file and rename to the extension .jpg, I can open the image directly on my mac with preview.

Comment: Not if you `Compress` it first.

Comment: That's true. So I should use CompressionLevel option in  ExportString instead of Compress!

Comment: The problem with `Compress` that I see is that it seems pointless to export to a commong standard like JSON and put stuff into it that only Mathematica can read. Why are you exporting to JSON in the first place?  On the other hand, if you don't `Compress` I doubt that what `ExportString[_,"JPEG"]` will create is in general a legal JSON string, (you'd need check the JSON standard definition for what is OK). If you need to read with other software I'd consider something like a hex encoded jpeg ("Base64" or "UUE"), which I think is also a more or less standard way to handle binary data in JSON.

Comment: @AlbertRetey you're right doesn't work without compress

Comment: @AlbertRetey I want to export an association with heterogeneous data (including images) to a static file of some standard format, seems ridiculous but I still haven't found a way to do that!

Comment: you could as I mentioned use some JSON-compliant encoding to store binary data in JSON as a string, but as JSON doesn't per se know anything about pictures the "receiving" side would have to know how to decode the corresponding strings and how to interpret the binary data. If you write or define the receiving side yourself that is no problem, otherwise JSON probably is not the format to choose. Can you give more specific requirements of "some standard format"? Maybe someone can suggest an alternative then...

Comment: @AlbertRetey a static database file perhaps?

Comment: If you think about access/dbase/sqlite I'd think they are not a very good fit, your data seems to be hierarchical rather than relational by nature. If you don't want to reorganize it, I'd rather think one of the scientific formats (FITS, NetCDF,HDF5) or even a zip-archive might be a potential fit. Of the scientific formats I have only experience with HDF5 which would even support image data but unfortunately that is one of the features that I think Mathematica does not really support. A good choice depends very much on what you are using to read those files...

Comment: I tried fits and hdf5 they don't work with this example either